# "Discord.py" Is there a way to reset someones nickname inmediately when someone changes it?

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started making a discord bot for my friend's server, but i wonder if there's a way to reset someones nickname inmediately once someone changes it. I assume that's possible with a `client.event` but i'm not sure.

I hope i'm clear in my question and that someone knows a way!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_#discord.on_member_update)

An example could be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.nick != after.nick:
         await after.edit(nick=before.nick)
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Only problem now is that the bot doesn't have permissions... :-{

Comment: You'll have to grant it a role (if it doesn't have its own role already) and give that role the Manage Nicknames permission. You could add a `@`decorator for this so the bot can check if it has permissions with `@bot_has_permissions(manage_nicknames=True)`